# AMP error: Missing supported structured data element

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-search-console, structured-data, amp-html

I have an aggregator site for books. I created dedicated AMP (Accelerated Mobile Page) for each book.

- Example AMP URL: `http://konyvar.hu/amp/nicholas-sparks/az-utolso-dal`
- Example canonical URL: `http://konyvar.hu/nicholas-sparks/az-utolso-dal`

In Google Webmaster Tools, I see the following error for this page:

> Missing supported structured data element

Google offers me to [Open Test Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fkonyvar.hu%252Famp%252Fnicholas-sparks%252Faz-utolso-dal), but it says:

> All good

Please help me, I have no idea, what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Am looking at `http://konyvar.hu/amp/nicholas-sparks/az-utolso-dal`. I think you'll need to declare the `AMP` page as a `NewsArticle` or `Blog` in a `JSON-LD` script.

Am looking at `https://hikingguy.com/hiking-trails/phoenix-hiking/mcdowell-sonoran-preserve-hike/amp/` . The `"@type": "Review"` is not yet supported. TTBOMK, only `Article` `NewsArticle` and `Blog` are acknowledged by Google. Try one of those and tell us what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that...google is not showing product reviews structure data for search carousel (AMP) Currently,

Only news article is showing in search carousel (AMP) Currently,. So technically your pages don't meet the requirement or are missing the required structured data elements to be shown in the carousel.

Wait until google start supporting  "@type": "Review"

**Please don't mark your content as news article it might degrade your current position in search results because your content is not related to that.**