# Using AMP-HTML on ecommerce product

Tags: amp-html

We are still getting error on Google Search Console about AMP: 
AMP validating: Missing required structured data element on this amp page.

With validator (https://validator.ampproject.org) we got Validation Status: PASS

We are using meta data and google structured data testing tools shows no errors and no warings.

This is one example url: 
(Don´t want to spam so additional space written to avoid linking)

https:// www. alpel.es/cosmo-nails-liquido-porcelana-uv-50-ml_amp

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check the [Structure Data policies](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#multiple-entities-on-the-same-page) for this:

> Multiple entities on the same page
>
> When you have multiple entity types on a page, we recommend you mark
>   up all entities on that page to help Google algorithms better
>   understand and index your content. For example:
>
> A recipe page might have text describing the recipe along with an
>   accompanying video. Each of these types should be marked separately
>   with schema.org/Recipe and schema.org/VideoObject respectively. A
>   category page listing several different products (or recipes, videos,
>   or any other type). Each entity should be marked up using the relevant
>   schema.org type, such as schema.org/Product for product category
>   pages. Marking up just one category entity from all listed on the page
>   is against our guidelines. A video play page might have related videos
>   embedded in a separate section on the page. In this case, mark up the
>   main video as well as the related videos. Image markup guidelines
>
> When marking up an image URL as a property of a type, make sure that
>   the image actually belongs to the instance of that type. For example,
>   if you mark up the schema.org/image property of
>   schema.org/NewsArticle, the marked-up image must directly belong to
>   that news article.

You may also check the [Product Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products).

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403976/amp-error-missing-supported-structured-data-element) and [this discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/nNjgf0szrSA;context-place=forum/webmasters) might help as well.

Comment: I think the problem was that we were using <article> to products, we've remove it so hope the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: @noogui. I got error. Could you please see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199925/external-style-sheet-is-not-working-in-amp-pages

Comment: @varunsharma I think it's on [disallowed list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages#disallowed-styles).

Comment: @Noogui. thanks for response. I followed these thinks. But How to access external style sheet. Because I cant include in inline.Because it is so long. (MaterializeCss). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199925/external-style-sheet-is-not-valid-in-amp-pages

Comment: @noogui. My question link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199925/external-style-sheet-is-not-valid-in-amp-pages

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna need to add a JSON-LD structure using schema.org. You can use Microdata (`itemprop`) if you chose, but it is not a substitute for the JSON-LD structure. The structure can go in `<body>` (previously was limited to `<head>`) and can be adjacent to the Microdata specifications.

Here is a structure you can modify to meet your needs:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json" id="20">
{
"@context":
 {
  "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
  "id": "@id",
  "graph": "@graph",
  "type": "@type"
 },
"graph":
 [
  {
  "type": "Product",
  "id": "http://example.com/identifier/type/Product/19000000001001",
  "name": "",
  "alternateName": "",
  "description": "",
  "releaseDate": "2016-01-02",
  "manufacturer":
   {
   "type": "Corporation",
   "id": "Company IRI"
   },
  "offers":
   {
   "type": "Offer",
   "price": "",
   "priceCurrency": "USD",
   "id": "http://example.com/identifier/type/Intangible/Offer/14180000001007"
   },
  "isSimilarTo":
   [
    {
    "type": "Product",
    "id": "http://example.com/identifier/type/Product/1001"
    },
    {
    "type": "Product",
    "id": "http://example.com/identifier/type/Product/1002"
    }
   ],
  "isRelatedTo":
   [
    {
    "type": "Product",
    "id": "http://example.com/identifier/type/Product/1003"
    },
    {
    "type": "Product",
    "id": "http://example.com/identifier/type/Product/1004"
    }
   ],
  "audience":
   [
    {
    "type": "BusinessAudience",
    "id": "http://example.com/identifier/type/Intangible/Role/14290000001001"
    },
    {
    "type": "BusinessAudience",
    "id": "http://example.com/identifier/type/Intangible/Role/14290000001003"
    }
   ],
  "category":
   [
    {
    "type": "Thing",
    "id": "http://example.com/identifier/type/Product/1010"
    },
    {
    "type": "Thing",
    "id": "http://example.com/identifier/type/Product/1012"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
</script>
```

You'll want to replace the technique-in-use for specifying unique identifiers (`"id":`) with your own technique.

Each of your `@Product` items (with their unique `@id`) should be included in the `@graph`.