# AMP: don't know which "structured data element" to add

Tags: amp-html

I created my first AMP and it got indexed by Google. When I check in Search Console there's an issue called "Missing structured data element: add structured data element". When I validate my AMP it's valid without any issues... What can I do to fix this issue?

URL: http://www.alderlane.ca/about/amp/

Comment: Should this be tagged amp-html instead of amp?

Comment: Please post your code here (and format it), instead of having people go to your page and then view the source. That way it's much easier to see what you are asking, and the question may help others even after your web page has changed.

Comment: The code is too long to post in a comment, you can see the code here: http://pastebin.com/dcyABKvd

Comment: this problem seems similar to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403976/amp-error-missing-supported-structured-data-element).

Comment: @noogui Looks like it, it's a thread from more than 6 months ago. Or Google didn't do anything yet, or the problem is something else.

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion more than a bug (I believe they class it as an Info warning).

A structured data element normally refers to some [Schema markup](http://schema.org) to help classify your website.

A common one would be to mark up your page as an [Article](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles).